# How to stop Pivot table in excel from refreshing when adding filters

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I need to set a pivot chart so it won't shrink when there are fewer data using date filter even if there isn't any data at that time. for example, in year 2019 there is 350 lines in 2018 there are 276 lines and 2019 and 2018 have 395 lines. I need it so when I see just 2019 or 2018 it shows all 395 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Open the PivotField's "Field Settings" menu (either right click on the PivotField, or click on it in the Field list)

On the "Layout and Print" tab, you will see an option marked "Show items with no data".

Tick it.

Comment: @MārtiņšTereško If this has solved your issue, please hit the Green Tick next to the question, to mark it as "Solved", and make it easier for other people to find if they have the same issue :)